# regular expression for matching number and spaces

Tags: php, regex

i want to create a regular expression which will allow only spaces and number..

And how can i check this with PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9 ]+$/';

if ( preg_match ($pattern, $text) )
{
    echo 'allowed';
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to limit to 15 chars (as you mentioned in a comment) you can use { } to delimit a min and a max lenght.

pattern becomes :

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9 ]{1,15}$/';
```

to allow 1 to 15 chars.

Answer (score 5):

The regex is as follows.

```
/^[\d ]+$/i
```

To answer how you run it in php, I need to know the context, do you need it to run on a single line or multi line input? do you need it to run in a loop?

Comment: single line only about 15 chars only

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
^[\s\d]*$
```

You should probably specify if you want "zero or more" or "one or more" spaces.  The above allows for an empty string to pass evaluation.

Comment: This one is exactly like the one I posted, except allows empty strings to pass, and tabs instead of spaces, if they happen.

Comment: \s allows all kind of characters, assuming he wants to allow only 'space' (0x32) it's not enough.