# how to filter array value that contains numbers only

Tags: php

I have a file as array 
'line number' => 'it's content';
now i need a way to remove lines that contains only numbers (without letters or special caracters) 
i did it by the length of the line but this method is not appropriate because it might delete some of the contents

```
/*count file lines*/
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}
fclose($handle);

for($i=0; $i<=($linecount*2)-4;$i++) {
    $length = strlen((string)$text[0][$i]);
    if ($length >5) 
    {
        echo ($text[0][$i] .'</br>');
    }

}
```

is_numric didn't work i think because there is a space before the numbers

Comment: What about using `is_numeric($value)`

Comment: already tried that but didn't work, i guess that's because there is spaces before the numbers

Comment: try using regex for this

Comment: perhaps providing some sample data might help others understand the problem better?

Comment: If there are spaces, then use `is_numeric(trim($value));`...

Comment: Rasclatt, thank you it works perfect now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the second line. Didn't understand why $length>5,it should $length>0

```
strlen(trim((string)$text[0][$i]));

for($i=0; $i<=($linecount*2)-4;$i++) {
$length = strlen(trim((string)$text[0][$i]));
if ($length >0) 
   {
       echo ($text[0][$i] .'</br>');
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$keys=array_filter(array_keys($array1), "is_numeric");
$out =array_diff_key($array1,array_flip($keys));
print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9 ]+$/';

if ( !preg_match ($pattern, $text) )
{
    echo 'allowed';
}
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698950/regular-expression-for-matching-number-and-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

As there was no example data given I have based this answer upon an assumed data input given the description - it may well bear no resemblance to the actual data.

The input file I used has the following lines of data - a mix of characters and numbers

```
abc23
123
89
gh46m
12 34 56


$file='c:/temp/src.txt';

$lines=array_filter( file( $file ), function( $item ){
    $pttn='@^[0-9\s]{1,}$@';
    preg_match( $pttn, $item ,$matches );
    return count( $matches ) > 0 ? true : false;
});

echo '<pre>',print_r($lines,true),'</pre>';
```

This outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 123

    [2] => 89

    [4] => 12 34 56
)
```

If a `space` counts as a special character then simply modify the regex pattern by removing `\s` and that should match only numbers